# Using backbone object.off with react class method callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js

*I'm usign react with backbone.*

I have tried different approaches and can't make the `off` method in `backbone` works, Apparently the context of `this.update` is not being pickup/access by backbone and can't remove it. I tested extracting `this.update` and putting before the class making the function global, like `MyStatic.update = function update() { // do stuff }` and the `off` method works but stop working as soon I bind `this` to the method inside the class like `some.backbone.object.on('change:total_score', MyStatic.update.bind(this));`

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I'm new to backbone and I really need to remove the event as soon the component `willComponentMount` get execute. any ideas?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SomeClass extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    some.backbone.object.off('change:total_score', this.update);
    some.backbone.object.on('change:total_score', this.update);
  }


  update() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I already tried to bind and use the arrow function in different ways and context

this.update = this.update.bind(this); //in constructor

const update = () => this.update(); // before the `off` method

what I'm doing right now which is working I created a static function which is not binded, so Backbone can find the reference and remove the event with the `off` method and then I'm passing the instance reference via a global object that I'm already had declared in my entire app, not the most elegant way but it's working, if somebody knows how to fix it in a better way, would be great.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SomeClass extends Component {

  static myUpdate = () => {
    const context = someGlobalStore.context;
    context.update();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    someGlobalStore.context = this;
    some.backbone.object.off('change:total_score', SomeClass.myUpdate);
    some.backbone.object.on('change:total_score', SomeClass.myUpdate);
  }

  update() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you bind a function, it returns a new function. That has a different reference to the original function or another bound function.

What I would recommend you to do is to bind the function in constructor and use in componentWillMount like this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SomeClass extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
     }
     componentWillMount() {
        const dataTable = this.connectData();
        this.setState({
          dataTable,
         });

        some.backbone.object.off('change:total_score', this.update);
        some.backbone.object.on('change:total_score', this.update);
     }


     update() {
       // do something
     }
}
```

Also, if you are using es7 package in babel. You can define arrow function in class itself and will not have to use bind at all.

Comment: I already tried that, thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason backbone lose the pointer to the function when bind is apply, I think what's is happening is that backbone tries to access the function inside of the backbone context, What I end doing is creating a static method which is not bind, and the pass the context of the class instance via an `store` / global variable. I don't think is the more elegant way (but it's working), but still don't understand why bind affect automatically backbone

Comment: When you bind/use arrow function, context of function will not change. The first time component mounts is the function already attached to the event?